# How to uninstall older version of Unity on Mac

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, uninstallation

I have installed several versions of Unity, such as `2019.1.8f1`, `2019.1.2f1`, `2018.2.21f1`. I'd like to delete specific (older) version of Unity on macOS Sierra. I can just remove reference from Unity Hub, but I want to delete files and components to increase disk space.

There are many articles about Windows, but I could not find about Mac.

Comment: usually Unity is installed entirely to one folder so you can simply delete that install folder (at least on windows .. just guess it is the same for Mac). Otherwise inside the folder you usually should find an uninstaller I guess

Comment: Thank you. This will be true. I found just only one version of Unity in Applications folder, and I tried launch older version of Unity, but it showed version mismatched error. So I think I only had latest version of Unity in real.

Comment: Usually if you install them via the HUB you can also uninstall them via the HUB but otherwise you have to do it manually ..

Comment: OK I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open unity hub and click on an installation you can right-click on three dots and click reveal in finder. This will show you the location of the unity install and from there you should be able to delete the folder.

[image: Unity Hub]

For me, it appears that the install location is a folder in my applications called Unity. It may be different for you but this should help you find the folder location.

[image: open]

Comment: In my case, all of installed versions pointed the same Unity app. It was maybe overwritten by accident (I also try launching older one, but it showed version mismatching error message). So I just deleted older versions from hub. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Usually Unity installs completely to one folder. So you can always simply delete the entire folder and should have no trouble.

If you installed Unity via the HUB than you should be able to directly uninstall it via the HUB.

If instead you installed Unity separately (e.g. before the HUB) and later added the installs manually you will have to go to the according folder and delete it manually.

In the second case Unity HUB is not updated so it is possible that it shows some entries for installs even though these installs are not on your PC anymore. Usually if you hit <kbd>Reveal in Finder</kbd> but nothing happens that means it doesn't exist on your machine anymore.

---

*Note: Windows User here so I don't have a Mac to confirm this but that is how it works on Windows and I expect it to behave the same on Mac*

Answer (score 0):

Note, that if you *really* want Unity Hub & Unity to go away, you'll also need to remove the folder `~/Library/Application Support/{Unity, Unity Hub}`.

You'd want to do this, for example, if you were cleaning up a machine prior to creating a tutorial on installing Unity or to test an installation procedure.